# Examples of Noetherian integral group ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings, noetherian

I need to study the integral group ring of the fundamental group of a manifold. My knowledge of group and ring theory is very limited. I am looking for some examples of groups $G$ for which $\Bbb ZG$ is Noetherian. So far, I understand that in the following cases, $\Bbb ZG$ becomes Noetherian:

- $G$ is finite,
- $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group,
- $G$ is a virtually polycyclic group (due to P. Hall).

Could you please provide some more examples, possibly with proofs or references?

Comment: Note that the first two items are covered by the third (virtually polycyclic). It is an open question (I guess it is in Baumslag's list?) whether virtually polycyclic groups these are the only ones. An obvious fact is that $G$ has to be noetherian, which discards most cases. A more recent result is that $G$ has to be amenable; this shows that there are noetherian groups (non-amenable Tarski monsters) with non-noetherian group ring. (Actually, it is unknown, as far as I know, whether there is a noetherian amenable group that is not virtually polycyclic. This can't be elementary amenable.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no known examples of groups with Noetherian integral group rings other than virtually polycyclic groups. The following result and subsequent text is quoted from

*Kropholler, Peter; Lorensen, Karl*, [**Group-graded rings satisfying the strong rank condition**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2019.08.014), J. Algebra 539, 326-338 (2019). [ZBL1453.16046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1453.16046).

**Corollary B.** Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a domain. If $SG$ is either right or left Noetherian, then $G$ is amenable and every subgroup of $G$ is finitely generated.

*Corollary B is relevant to the longstanding conjecture that, if $G$ is a group such that $\mathbb{Z}G$ is either left or right Noetherian, then G must be virtually polycyclic. The corollary lends further credence to this conjecture, for the only amenable groups known in which every subgroup is finitely generated are those that are virtually polycyclic.*